# Comparing discretized manifolds

Tags: computational-geometry, discrete-geometry

being quite unsure which keywords to search with, I have a quick question on comparing discrete manifolds:

Let's say we have have two smooth $2$-manifolds $M1$ and $M2$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Of these only discretizations are known.

I would like to approximately calculate (as in calculate with a computer) the difference between those manifolds (aka point-wise $"-"$ in $R^3$) based on these discretizations.

Are you aware of any papers/books published regarding this topic, or keywords to search for?

Thanks in advance and please feel free to point out any stupidities in this question.